# Which settings apply to a folder connected via junction?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, symlink, share, junction

Which folder permission and folder sharing settings apply to a a folder "connected" within another folder via junction, or symlink?

Lets assume we have two folders residing in drive `D:`. `D:\Main` `D:\Other`. I create a junction in `D:\Main\jOther` which points to `D:\Other`.

`Security settings` and `sharing settings` of which of the folders `D:\Main` & `D:\Other` will `D:\Main\jOther` respect? Or does it have settings of its own?